# NT Security Descriptor

Tags: active-directory, permissions, file-permissions, access-control-list, user-permissions

In active directory an object have several permissions on many objects.
how to view permissions of particular object?

i am asking like for eg user Kavin have read permissions on some folder, full control on some other folders and Kavin have edit membership of group permissions.

how to view these permissions of object Kavin?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to know or view what permissions a security principal may have to resources.

Comment: To expand on this - the permissions are on the objects, not the principal. You could certainly list every object in your domain (and any trusted domains), and review every ACL for the presence of Kevin's account SID. But you can't look at Kevin alone and know what any of his permissions are.